# when a condition satisfied redirect to one page if failed redirect to another page using success url in class based views

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

when the if condition  is valid then i want to redirect the page to success.html page and if not valid redirect to faild.html page.How can it possible using class based views.

```
class LogView(FormView):
    form_class = LogForm
    template_name = 'log.html'
    success_url='failed'
    def get_success_url(self):
        if not self.success_url:
                raise ImproperlyConfigured("No URL to redirect 
                to.Provide a success_url.")
        return str(self.success_url) 

    def form_valid(self,form):
            cc=''
            nam1 = self.request.POST.get('nam')
            roll1 = self.request.POST.get('roll')
            obj=Register.objects.all()
            for i in obj:
                if  str(i.name) == str(nam1) and  str(i.rollno) == str(roll1):




                else:
                    pass
            else:
                pass
```

Comment: what is your condition ?

Comment: if  str(i.name) == str(nam1) and  str(i.rollno) == str(roll1):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `form_valid` and `form_invalid` method for this:

```
class LogView(FormView):
    form_class = LogForm
    template_name = 'log.html'
    success_url='failed'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        """
        If the form is valid, redirect to the supplied URL.
        """
        nam1 = self.request.POST.get('nam')
        roll1 = self.request.POST.get('roll')
        obj=Register.objects.filter(name=nam1, rollno=roll1).exists()
        if  obj:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('failed')   

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        """
        If the form is invalid
        """
        return HttpResponseRedirect('some_invalid_url')
```

Comment: when a false condition occures how can i redirect ? my  code is written below

Comment: @Anjitha just add `else: return HttpResponseRedirect('some_invalid_url')`

Comment: then, both if and else conditions goes to the same page (only else part executed)

Comment: what i done is i written in below answer,pls chech that

Comment: @Anjitha your code looks good. Probably you dont have any objects with prvided `name` and `rollno` in DB?

Comment: @Anjitha the problem is in your program logic. Program will do redirect right after first record in DB. So if conditions for first record are met you will be redirected to succes, otherwise to the failed.

Comment: you said it.its works nicely only for first element in db..How can i avoid such condition?

Comment: @Anjitha try to use another queryset: `obj=Register.objects.filter(name=nam1, rollno=roll1).exists()` see updated answer.

Comment: that query very helpfull.Now its working nicely.Thank you.

Comment: I added the final correct code in below answer section

Answer (score 0):

```
 class LogView(FormView):
    form_class = LogForm
    template_name = 'log.html'
    success_url='success'
    def form_valid(self, form):
        nam1 = self.request.POST.get('nam')
        roll1 = self.request.POST.get('roll')
        obj=Register.objects.filter(name=nam1, rollno=roll1).exists()
        if (obj==True):
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('failed')
```